# Is there any alternative term for ‘syntactic word’?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

What do you call *a group of adjacent letters having punctuation except for apostrophes on either side*? For example, in this sentence, the groups are `Let's`, `see`, `the`, `fireworks`:

> Let's see the fireworks.

Assuming a *word* is *a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing that consists of one or more morphemes*, what I'm asking is different from a *word*: `let`, `us`, `see`, `the`, `firework`.

---

I'm looking for an English equivalent of a Korean word `Madi`<sup>[[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%A7%88%EB%94%94)[[2]](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12423100&directAnchor=s125996p456188d522256)</sup> (or `Sojeol (小節)`<sup>[[1]](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=21988200&directAnchor=s223136p142726d591496)</sup>) meaning such a letter group. Since there're some *words* that are not spaced (e.g. pre/postpositions in Korean) in Korean, unlike English, `Madi` is commonly used as a distinctive term as to `Nanmal`<sup>[[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%82%B1%EB%A7%90)[[2]](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=7100400&directAnchor=s73933p47177d114212)</sup> (or `Daneo (單語)`<sup>[[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%8B%A8%EC%96%B4)[[2]](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=8638600&directAnchor=s89887p57347d123607)</sup>) meaning a *word*.

Comment: I would use "word".  I suppose if you have a need for more precision in a specific work of analysis one might invent (and clearly define) another term, such as "contiguous character sequence", but there should be no need for this in normal writing.  (And most folks here would probably consider "let's" to be a word.)

Comment: Are there no specific terms to disambiguate a `word` into [a ‘**semantic _word_**’ or a ‘**syntactic _word_**’](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/356bc2/are_contractions_in_english_considered_one_word/cr1dput/) in English; or any linguistic terms for it?

Comment: Perhaps phrase?  A word in English plus a preposition, for example?  In programming you'd call a contiguous character sequence a string.  You may be thinking of something like a phrasal verb, where the two parts produce a unique meaning, e.g., "put on"

Comment: How about `chunk`? Would it be generally acceptable?

Comment: It's about ASCII, not English. You can call it anything you like, since there's no linguistic term for it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but you could investigate the term 'orthographic word'. 'Word' is ill-defined when it comes to deciding on whether << ink well >> (open compound noun) should be considered one 'word' or two.

Comment: First find a translator fluent in both English and Korean, then re-phrase the Question, please.

‘a group of adjacent letters having punctuation except for apostrophes on either side’ has no meaning in English. 

If you want to consider a translation from another language please first name the language, then add the pure Roman alphabetic transliteration, then add one or more literal translations.

How could there be an English equivalent of Korean Madi or Sojeol, please? How do Korean Madi or Sojeol differ and what do they have in common, please?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there's any short and neat term for **text chunks separated by spaces**. Okay, the expression I wrote above would look quite long, but it's a thing called ‘being _very specific_.’ The Korean thing below is merely the context of this question.

Comment: Can you clarify "…a word is a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing that consists of one or more morphemes" and "what I'm asking is different"? How, please, is it different?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin As far as I know, we have two kinds of “words” in English: for instance, both `let` and `us` have their own distinct meanings, so one may consider `let's` to be “two words,” however, since they're running together, another may call it “a single word.” In this question, I'm asking about the latter “word,” which is different from the former “word,” “a single _distinct meaningful element_ of speech or writing that consists of one or more morphemes.”

Comment: Thanks K and whoever is your "we", if English recognised your 'two kinds of “words” ' then they'd be clearly explained in more than a few text books, don't you think? The problem here seems to be more that you want to re-define the idea of a word, than anything else.